# GitHub Actions for NodeJS Project that is dependent on using MicroPhone

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I am trying to execute my automated NodeJS test scripts using Github Actions. Some of my tests are dependent on using Microphones from the system as there is a voice recorder in my application. The tests that use the system microphone are not working on cloud in Github actions. Does anyone if there is any way to enable mic on any OS provided by Github - Mac, Windows, Ubuntu

```
name: Node.js CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: macos-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.16.3]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        browser: chrome  
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run test:e2e
```

Comment: Are you able to test this inside a Docker container locally? If so, you should be able to use the [`job.<job_id>.container`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) feature to execute your workflow in the same Docker image.

Comment: Hi @peterevans, No , I did not try this in a Docker container. Thanks for the suggestion. I can try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved after I added `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` in ChromeOptions